# I have a problem connecting to a PostgreSQL database with UiPath

Tags: postgresql, uipath

I have to build a bot with UiPath, connect to a PostgreSQL database, and then look the data from the database in another platform.

Comment: You will need to provide some actual details. All we know is that it doesn't work for you. Let's make it as simple as we can to start . Show how you are trying to connect from your bot and show us psql connecting with the same settings from the same machine.